# Ifelse statement with 4 conditions

Tags: r, if-statement

With the following sample data, I'm trying to create a new column "NOTA_NUM" (value 0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4) in my dataframe(df) based on the values of four conditional variables ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E") from one existing column (column1).

I have already tried:

```
df$NOTA_NUM <- ifelse(rowSums(df[ , "column1"]=="A"), 0,
        ifelse(rowSums(df[ , "column1"]=="B"), 1,
               ifelse(rowSums(df[ ,"column1"]=="C"), 2,
                      ifelse(rowSums(df[ , "column1"]=="D",3,4))
```

but that didn't work the way I would like.

I want "NOTA_NUM" to look like:

```
column1   NOTA_NUM
A             0
C             2
B             1
D             3
E             4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure that I'd recommend `as.numeric(factor(...))` as a general solution, but works for your case:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1001) # for reproducible sample
# column1 = factor as stringsAsFactors = TRUE (default)
data.frame(column1 = sample(LETTERS[1:5], 50, replace = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(NOTA_NUM = as.numeric(column1)-1)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It just worked the way I was looking for.

Comment: Code as written does assume `column1` is already a factor; you'd use `as.numeric(factor(column1))-1` if not.

Answer (score 4):

Here are some approaches. No packages are used.

**1) match** Using `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end match each element in `column1` to `LETTERS[1:4]` and use 5 if no match.  Subtract 1 from that.

```
transform(DF, NOIA_NUM = match(column1, LETTERS[1:4], nomatch = 5) - 1)
```

giving:

```
  column1 NOIA_NUM
1       A        0
2       C        2
3       B        1
4       D        3
5       E        4
```

**2) switch** Another possibility is to use `switch`:

```
transform(DF, NOTA_NUM = sapply(column1, switch, A = 0, B = 1, C = 2, D = 3, 4))
```

**3) arithmetic** This uses an arithmetic expression which evaluates to the required values:

```
transform(DF, NOTA_NUM = (0-4) * (column1 == "A") + 
                         (1-4) * (column1 == "B") + 
                         (2-4) * (column1 == "C") + 
                         (3-4) * (column1 == "D") + 
                         4)
```

### Note

```
DF <- data.frame(column1 =  c("A", "C", "B", "D", "E"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

I like `dplyr::case_when` for these situations:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(column1 = c("A", "C", "B", "D", "E")) %>% 
  mutate(NOTA_NUM = case_when(column1 == "A" ~ 0, 
                              column1 == "B" ~ 1, 
                              column1 == "C" ~ 2, 
                              column1 == "D" ~ 3, 
                              TRUE ~ 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid `ifelse` for this purpose. You should employ a more efficient and compact approach to a table lookup or conversion. Try using a named vector as the table and pass the inputs to the "[" function:

```
> lookup = c(A=0, C= 2, B =  1, D= 3, E = 4)
> df <- data.frame( cl1 = names(lookup))
> df
  cl1
1   A
2   C
3   B
4   D
5   E
> df$NOTA_NUM= lookup[df$cl1]
> df
  cl1 NOTA_NUM
1   A      0
2   C      1
3   B      2
4   D      3
5   E      4
```

If you need these to be letters then quote them in the lookup vector but beware that the data.frame function will make them factors unless you explicitly prevent that default action. See `?data.frame` for the proper use of `stringsAsFactors` parameter